# How map 2D matrix entries to 1D array with a "pointer array" indirection?

Tags: algorithm, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix

**Note: I've edited this question with the helpful feedback of [Keith Randall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180090/keith-randall) and [Chiyou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340457/chiyou).**

I have an idea to use 1D array to cache most used 2D NxM matrix entries in a particular processing context. The question is that does there exist already a body of work from where to gain insight or is there just people *in the know*. I will outline the leg-work first and ask the question later too. As an additional note, [Chiyou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340457/chiyou) already proposed [space filling curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), which look conceptually the thing I'm after, but won't readily answer to my specific question (i.e. I can't find a curve that would do what I'm after).

**The leg-work:**
Currently the *most used entries* are defined as a combination of loops and a special `pointer_array` (see code below), which in combination produce the indices to the most used matrix elements. The pointer_array contains numbers [in range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Excluding_the_endpoints) **[0, max(N, M)]** (see above matrix dimensions defined as NxM).

The purpose of the code is to produce a suitable (in context of the program) combination of indices to process some of the matrix entries. It's possible N = M, i.e. a square matrix. The code (C++) traversing the matrix would look like the following

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{        
    for(int j = i + 1; j < M; j++)
    {
        auto pointer1 = pointer_array[i];
        auto pointer2 = pointer_array[i + 1];
        auto pointer3 = pointer_array[j];
        auto pointer4 = pointer_array[j + 1];

        auto entry1 = some_matrix[pointer1][pointer3];
        auto entry2 = some_matrix[pointer2][pointer4];
        auto entry3 = some_matrix[pointer3][pointer4];
        auto entry4 = some_matrix[pointer1][pointer2];

        //Computing with the entries...
    }
}
```

Some things worth of separate note:

1. To make this caching worthwhile, I think it should be dense. That is, something that can be accessed in random and is laid out contiguosly in memory. I.e. no space "wasted" (except maybe if there are many separate chunks) and complexity is in O(1). It would mean the cache can't be the same 2D matrix ordered in its entirety as a 1D row/column-major ordered array. I feel it should fit into an array having length **max(N, M)** (see above matrix dimension definition).
2. Many of the entries in `some_matrix` will be ignored during the loops.
3. The pointer_array ordering records *a route through the matrix*, so it's used elsewhere too.
4. I've come across this need in various occasions, but this time I've written a [2-opt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-opt) algorithm, memory access pattern of which I'm seeking to improve. I'm aware there are other ways to write the algorithm (but see the point there are other settings I've come across this and am now wondering if there were a general solution).
5. Outside of the box thinking would be to produce a similar kind of combination of indices to something that is conceptually like accessing a 2D matrix, but only smarter. One option would be to cache matrix rows/columns during looping.
6. As the entries will be used a lot, so it would be more ideal to replace the `pointer_array` indirection by caching the some_matrix calls so that acquiring the `entry*` values in the loops would be faster, i.e. from a pre-loaded cache instead of possibly rather big matrix. Other point here is that it would save in storage, which in turn means the often used values could very well fit a faster cache.

**Question:** Is it possible to device an indexing scheme so that the matrix indexing would essentially become

```
//Load the 2D matrix entries to some_1d_cache using the pointer_array
//so that the loop indices can be used directly...

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{        
    for (int j = i + 1; j < M; j++)
    {           
        //The some_1d_cache((x, y) call will calculate an index to the 1D cache array...
        auto entry1 = some_1d_cache(i, j);
        auto entry2 = some_1d_cache(i + 1, j + 1);
        auto entry3 = some_1d_cache(j, j + 1);
        auto entry4 = some_1d_cache(i, i + 1);

        //Computing with the entries...
    }
}
```

Or maybe something like following would do too

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{        
    for (int j = i + 1; j < M; j++)
    {            
        auto pointer1 = pointer_array[i];
        auto pointer2 = pointer_array[i + 1];
        auto pointer3 = pointer_array[j];
        auto pointer4 = pointer_array[j + 1];

        //The some_1d_cache((x, y) call will calculate an index to the 1D cache array...
        auto entry1 = some_1d_cache(pointer1, pointer3);
        auto entry2 = some_1d_cache(pointer2, pointer4);
        auto entry3 = some_1d_cache(pointer3, pointer4);
        auto entry4 = some_1d_cache(pointer1, pointer2);

        //Computing with the entries...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this question is cryptic.  What are you trying to cache, exactly?  Parts of the matrix?  If so, then what's the access pattern?  Clearly if I'm just walking through the whole matrix caching isn't going to help at all.

Comment: Keith, yes, I'm trying to cache a part of the matrix. The part to cache are pointed by the indices in pointer_array. The access pattern is the one described in the loops.

Comment: So you're trying to cache the upper triangular part of an NxM matrix?  Any by cache, you mean allocate to a contiguous chunk of memory?

Comment: Yes, I aim to allocate a contiguous chunk of memory, mainly an 1D array is my target due to (currently perceived) simplicity. I'm not trying to cache upper triangular part of the matrix, but the loop indices provide indices to the pointer_array, which in turn contain the desired matrix indices. The call could be something like some_matrix[0][10] and some_matrix[10][0] during the same run. I'll edit the question regarding this (and fix the index condition bug there).

Comment: Sorry, I give up.  I still don't understand what the point of all this is.  Maybe write the loop for what you're trying to do with a plain, row-major layout?  Or is that your first code snippet?  But then why does your first code snippet not just do `auto entry1 = some_matrix[i][j]`?  What's the point of `pointer_array`?  Is it aliasing entries to the same storage?

Comment: Keith, I edited the question to make it clearer. No offence taken, this, I could have been clearer. I'm also starting to think this isn't that easy a problem to crack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index a 2d matrix with a 1d space filling curve. Mathematically it's H(x,y) = (h(x) * h(y)). They are also useful because they basically subdivide, store some locality information and reorder the plane.

Comment: Hey, Chiyou, this is a useful pointer, definitely something to use with search engines. I'll examine this line of thought more closely during the week.